# Phonegap in Visual Studio 2012 : how to use console.log?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap 3.0.0 and I need to debug a Windows Phone 8 App.

The PhoneGap WP8 documentation is outdated since it's about a downloaded version though NodeJS seems to be mandatory with version 3.0.0.

I can open the project generated by PhoneGap with VS2012 but I don't see any log in the console... Did anybody have the same problem ?

*PhoneGap WP8 doc*: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add your answer you should create an actual answer. This will help other people looking at your question in the future as it makes it more obvious that you've found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution: you need to run the application in debug mode (unlike android).

Answer (score 0):

During the Debugg process, go to Debug>Window>JavaScript Console or press Strg+Alt+V

Now you must see the console.log output